# TeamCity GIt lab merge request not triggering a build

Tags: merge, continuous-integration, teamcity, gitlab

We are trying to have a build triggered on a merge request, but it's not happening, we followed http://www.nguyenquyhy.com/2017/10/how-to-integrate-teamcity-and-gitlab-ci/, with no luck.

Is it feasible to trigger the build when a merge request is created ?

We are using:
“TeamCity 2017.2.3 (build 51047), effective release date 2017-11-27, currently running in the professional mode.
Maximum number of authorized agents: 3 agents provided by professional edition license
Maximum number of build configurations: 100 build configurations provided by professional edition license ”
And gitLab as a hosted service.

Comment: I think that is possible by adding a trigger in GitLab. You can either use `curl` or `API` for doing this. You may consider referring this: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks on the comment.
As specified in the mentioned article, we needed to add this into the VCS root:

```
"+:refs/heads/(*) and +:/refs/(merge-requests/*)/head"
```

This actually gets the merge requests available as branches to be built from.

Well we sorted out by creating a trigger with a slightly different format:
     "+:merge-requests/*"

This triggers the build when a merge request.